# Disable new line in multi line text box and set next focus on enter key

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to disable New line in my multi line text box. I am using multi line text box because the field contains very long description. Also I am setting next focus in my text box as follows:

```
if (e.KeyChar == 13)
   SendKeys.Send("\t");
```

I am doing this in Keypress event, but what it does is it Sets a new line in text box as well. Also when I press enter when the text is selected then it clears the box and creates a new line.

Any help would highly be appreciated.

I want to prevent new line and set next focus on Enter key press.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you should use `KeyDown` Event instead of `KeyPress` so that you can suppress the event, and achieve desire result

```
private void Txtbx_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode.Equals(Keys.Enter))
   {
            SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I have added other code in KeyPress as well, I cannot suppress key press.

Comment: @JaydipJ, I think you mean suppress, not surpass?

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use the SelectNextControl()-Method (on your textbox) instead of SendKeys. See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.selectnextcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx